# Como hago esta consulta SQL en Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Necesito hacer esta consulta SQL en laravel.

> SELECT * FROM `platoIngrediente` WHERE `plato_id` = 1

PlatoIngrediente es mi tabla, plato_id es un campo que esta dinámico por una llave foránea.

Tengo el método show en el controlador de platoIngrediente, donde me pasa un $id... tengo algo como esto.

```
public function show($id)
    {
        ->where('plato_id', '=', '$id')
        ->get();
    }
```

esa $id la tengo en un select en mi vista que el usuario elige, esta como POST en mi vista.

Comment: @Shaz Se me pasó completamente, una disculpa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás usando Eloquent y tienes bien definidos los modelos y sus relaciones, deberías poder hacer algo así:

```
PlatoIngrediente::whereHas('plato', function($query) use ($id) {
    $query->whereId($id);
})
->get();
```

Lo que este código hace es obtener todos los platos ingredientes que tengan un relacionados el plato con el id definido.

---

Si dicha consulta es muy compleja para ti, entonces puedes hacer algo similar a lo que intentas, aunque NO LO RECOMIENDO:

```
PlatoIngrediente::wherePlatoId($id)->get();
```

Por favor revisa la documentación de Laravel:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence